# Add new field in WordPress Menu to output in theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a simple class or function to extend the WordPress default menu items with new custom fields?

For example, when you go to Appearance - Menus, add a new menu and drag/drop an item to your menu, that actual item has few hidden fields that can be enabled from Screen Options:

- Title Attribute
- Description

My question is: how to add another custom field there? Like a background field to write the text there and output it in my custom theme like we output the title and description:

```
<?php echo $navItem->description; ?>
```

Changed the html code live on the admin page, so you can catch my idea on what I want to do.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACF is the plugin just what you looking for. Create as many fields as your want, assign it to manu form and you are done.

[image: Menu Fields]

For more information follow this URL,

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Installed the plugin, but it seems that "Menu Item" is not available for me in Location Rules. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Oh I get it now. After some research, this option is available only for the Pro version. Thanks! I will mark your answer as correct!

Comment: Ok, I was also not aware of that, as I always use the pro version. Pro version is worth a purchase. You can just do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

follow this URL may help you
Adding custom Fields to WordPress Navigation Menu Items
http://jafty.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-wordpress-navigation-menu-items/